# Struct initialized in function loses values (although it's an array)

Tags: c, struct, pass-by-reference, adt

I'm trying to initialize array *dip inside "leggif1", inside it if you do a print it's all normal but if you try to print in the main, after the initialization, everything loses its values.
Same thing happen with ADT of first grade "Divisione" and i can't understand why (even though they are passed "by reference" thanks to their pointers).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct {
  int matricola;
  char nome[20+1],cognome[20+1];
  int comp[4];            
}dipendente;

typedef struct divisione  *Divisione;
struct divisione{
dipendente *dip;
char nome[10+1];
int terna[4][3];        //numero minimo di addetti,competenza minima totale, competenza ottimale totale
                        //per ognuna delle 4 tipologie
};

void leggif1(dipendente *dip, char *filename);
int leggif2(Divisione *Div, char *filename);
void DIVstampa(Divisione *Div,char *filename,int D);
Divisione DIVinit();
void DIVfree(Divisione *Div);

int main(int argc,char **argv) {
dipendente *dip;
Divisione *Div;
leggif1(dip,argv[1]);
int D=leggif2(Div, argv[2]);
DIVstampa(Div,"stdout",D);

return 0;
}

void leggif1(dipendente *dip, char *filename) {
FILE *fp=fopen(filename,"r");
int i,N;

fscanf(fp,"%d",&N);
dip=malloc(N*sizeof(dipendente));

for(i=0;i<N;i++)
    fscanf(fp,"%d %s %s %d %d %d %d",&dip[i].matricola,dip[i].nome,dip[i].cognome,
           &dip[i].comp[0],&dip[i].comp[1],&dip[i].comp[2],&dip[i].comp[3]);

}

int leggif2(Divisione *Div, char *filename) {
FILE *fp=fopen(filename,"r");
int i,j,D;
fscanf(fp,"%d",&D);
Div=malloc(D*sizeof(Divisione));
for(i=0;i<D;i++)
    Div[i]=DIVinit();

for(i=0;i<D;i++) {
    fscanf(fp, "%s", Div[i]->nome);
    for (j = 0; j < 4; j++)
        fscanf(fp, "%d %d %d", &Div[i]->terna[j][0], &Div[i]->terna[j][1], &Div[i]->terna[j][2]);
}

return D;
}

void DIVstampa(Divisione *Div, char *filename, int D) {
FILE *fp;
if(strcmp(filename,"stdout")==0)
    fp=stdout;
else
    fp=fopen(filename,"w");

int i,j;
for(i=0;i<D;i++) {
    fprintf(fp,"%s\n", Div[i]->nome);
    for(j=0;j<4;j++)
        fprintf(fp,"%d %d %d\n", Div[i]->terna[j][0], Div[i]->terna[j][1], Div[i]->terna[j][2]);
}

}
Divisione DIVinit(){
Divisione Div=malloc(sizeof (*Div));
return Div;
}

void DIVfree(Divisione *Div){
free(Div);
}
```

Comment: You declare in `dipendente *dip;` a pointer to a structure, but to where does it point? You have undefined behaviour from the outset, so all other bets are off.

Comment: Please edit the question and fix the indention. This code isn't readable.

Answer (score 0):

The `leggif1` function ignores the value of `dip` and assigns it a new value. That value is never returned to main.

The type of `dip` is `dipendente*` and when called in main the value of the pointer is passed to the function. Overwriting that local copy in the function *does not* affect the value of the pointer in `main`.

C only has 'call by value', always make sure you known what that value represents.

This can be solved by *returning* the `dip` from the function instead of taking it as a parameter:

```
dipendente* leggif1(char *filename)
{
    //open file and read N
    dipendente *dip = malloc(N * sizeof *dip);
    if (!dip) {
        return NULL;
    }
    // read in the data

    return dip;
}
```

another way is to use a `dipendente**` (a pointer to a pointer) but that would, in this case, make the code needlessly complex.

The `leggif2` function has the same problem.

Comment: but  `*dip` is both pointer and array and arrays in  c are always passed by reference, so shouldn't this work with an array of struct as well? `@koder`

Comment: @BrcMat, but you are not passing an array, you are passing an uninitialized pointer. And if you pass an array, you can only change its contents. You cannot redefine the array itself.

Comment: ok thanks a lot for the effort koder, i'll keep that in mind.